# Semigroup with a property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given the semigroup $(S,*)$ with property that it holds that $(\forall x \in S)(\exists y \in S)(xyx=x)$. Let $aba=b$, prove that $ab$ and $ba$ are idempotent. And prove that there exists $c$ such that $aca=a$ and $cac=c$.
I proved that those elements are idempotent, but I'm stuck with second part, by property for every x including $a$ there should be $c$ such that $aca=a$, but what about $cac=c$ how to prove it?

Comment: Did you mean $aba=a$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(S,*)$ be a semigroup with the indicated property, and let $a∈S$.  Then there exists $b∈S$ such that $aba=a$.  You have shown that $ab$ and $ba$ are idempotents.  We want to prove that there exists $c∈S$ such that $aca=a$ and $cac=a$.

Let $c = bab$.  Then $$aca=a(bab)a=(ab)(ab)a = (ab)a=a$$ and $$cac=(bab)a(bab) = (ba)(ba)bab = (ba)bab=(ba)(ba)b = (ba)b=c.$$